# SPFx how to save some propeties to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, properties

I have got a SharePoint webpart written in SPFx.

I need a sample how to save some properties to SharePoint list.

Could You help me please ?

Comment: Are you using React web part or no javascript webpart?

Comment: I use javascript web part. And some code with react.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Sample code for CRUD operations on SharePoint using below link:

[GitHub - SharePoint CRUD operations](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud).

Also, you check below articles for step by step guide:

2. CRUD operations using SharePoint Framework webpart and PnPJS:

   - [SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-List-CRUD-WebPart-PnPJS](https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-List-CRUD-WebPart-PnPJS.html).
   - [CRUD Operations Using Sharepoint FrameWork And PnP JS Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-using-sharepoint-framework-and-pnp-js-library/).
3. SharePoint Framework - CRUD Operations Using No Framework and SPHTTPClient

   [SharePoint Framework - CRUD Operations Using No Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-crud-operations-using-no-framework/)